# UI is distored when keyboard is displayed on clicking on input type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iphone, cordova

I am have a Phonegap application which has a list view created using li tag. When clicked on "Search" a search div tag is displayed with a input field (textfield) and a "Cancel" button. The list view moves down to give space to the search panel.

When clicked on "Cancel" button without the focus being on input field, the search panel is hidden and the list view shifts back to its original position. But, when clicked on the input field the iOS keyboard is displayed. When clicked on "Cancel" button with the keyboard open, the list view shifts way up from its original position. Also the footer in the page is displayed half way in the screen for iPhone 5.

Have searched and tried a couple of options like calling window.scrollTo(0,0) when input in focused, resizing the window etc. but all in vain.

Any kind of assistance or help is welcome.

Comment: A screenshot would help.

Comment: I cannot add any image as I do not have more than 10 reputations. Sorry but it is restricted by site admin